# Verifying thread safety with JUnit

Tags: multithreading, junit

I would like to test if my code is thread safe by calling it from multiple threads at the same time with different parameters.
Below is an **example** of how the code I want to test looks like

```
public void writeStringToFile(String fileName, String toBeWritten) {
    //some implementation that junit should not care.
}
```

In the above code I want to verify if the code is thread safe if it is invoked with different file names from multiple threads at the same time.
How should I design my JUnit so that it is easy to understand and maintain?

Comment: If it is invoked with different filenames, how does ist need to be thread safe? How could it be unsafe? The interesting question would be to assure that with 2 same file names it does what you expect.

Comment: @Theolodis - The above code was just an example, probably not a concrete one. Code could be unsafe based on its implementation logic. In the above example assume you do not know the implementation, how would you test that it is thread safe if it is invoked with different file names from multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: well, your code is not thread safe since you didn't write it to be so. As @Theolodis said, for different file name - there's no problem, fir the same file - as I said - you didn't write it be thread safe so it would fail

Comment: In junit you could just start 2 threads doing some operations and check the variable, file or w/e you accessed on afterwards, supposing that you implemented some synchronisation or w/e. If we suppose that you do take a number, modify it in the function, and write it to the given file, do the above and check the content of the 2 files. If it contains what you expected it could be thread safe. But there is no real way to assure thread safety by 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the code to public void `writeStringToOutputStream(OutputStream out, String toBeWritten)` (or made this the actual implementation, and the original method just a thin wrapper), you could pass a FilterOutputStream that looks out for concurrent writes, possibly even blocking for a while so other potential concurrent writes can try to execute.

But this really only checks that the writes aren't concurrent, not that the class isn't thread-safe. If you detect concurrent writes, you could read back the data and make sure it's valid.